# Trying to return max date

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get the max date year value but I am getting the error `Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable`. is there something else I need to do to?

```
public int GetMeetingMaxYearBygroupId(int groupId)
        {
            using (var db = new NccnEcommerceEntities())
            {
                var q = from md in db.MeetingDates
                        join m in db.Meetings on md.MeetingId equals m.MeetingId
                        where (m.GroupId == groupId)
                        group md by md.StartDate into g
                        select new { Date = g.Max(t => t.StartDate) };

                int year = 2001;
                return year;

            }

        }
```

Comment: Sound like you are clicking on the results in the debug view.  That's just telling you that the expression you've written above has not been executed yet.  The above expression is an IQueryable and hasn't been evaluated yet.

Comment: Your code has some errors - you are grouping by `md.StartDate` which means each group `g` will have the same `StartDate` so why are you taking the `Max()`? What is the purpose of the `group by`? Can you better explain what "max date year value" you actually want - is it a single value? Is it a list of values?

Comment: I was trying to get the max startDate value just the single value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably see this message in your debugger. This is not a problem, or more precise: it might be a problem if you expand, but usually isn't.

### IQueryable and deferred execution

When using LINQ you'll have to be aware that there are two groups of LINQ functions. The ones that won't execute the query, and the ones that will fetch the data and start iterating.

The first group of LINQ methods, the ones that don't execute the query, can be recognized by the fact that they return `IQueryable<...>` (or `IEnumerable<...>`). It is often said that these methods use lazy execution. In the description of these methods, you will always see that they use deferred execution. A concatenation of these LINQ methods does not represent the data itself, it represents the **potentional** to fetch the data.

Concatenating these LINQ methods is not an expensive action. Concatenating IQueryables will only change the Expression of the IQueryable. The database is not contacted, no data is fetched yet.

The other group of methods, the ones that don't return `IQueryable<...>` will execute the query. These LINQ functions often use internally a `foreach`, or if it is more efficient, if will use `GetEnumerator()` to get the enumerator, and repeatedly call `MoveNext() and Current` to access the data.

`GetEnumerator()` will send the `IQueryable.Expression` to the `IQueryable.Provider`, who will translate it to SQL and contact the database to fetch the data. The fetched data is returned to the caller as an `IEnumerator<...>`, so the caller can call `MoveNext() / Current` to access the data.

### Back to your question

In the debugger you sometimes want to see the data that the IQueryable represents. The message `Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable` is just a warning, that if you expand the results to see the data, the database will be contacted and data will be fetched.

Apart from that this might take some time, some queries might change other data, for instance if you log somewhere when data was queried.

So usually it is not a problem to look at the data, especially during debugging non-production data. Only be aware that if you expand the data, then there might be side effects.

Answer (score 0):

`Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable` isn't an error, it's just Visual Studio saying what will happen when you expand the results view.

As far as I understand you need to do a `First` after your select, to bring the result into memory, otherwise whenever you reference `q` it will run the query again.